# Django sort posts by comments count

Tags: python, django

I have created two Django models namely Post and Comment.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

I would like to show all the posts on the homepage and order them by comments count. please help to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.annotate(
    ncomment=Count('comment')
).order_by('-ncomment')
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) you can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent calculating this both as column and in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.alias(
    ncomment=Count('comment')
).order_by('-ncomment')
```

If you thus for example work with a `ListView`, you override the `queryset` attribute with:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

MyListView(ListView):
    queryset = ost.objects.alias(
        ncomment=Count('comment')
    ).order_by('-ncomment')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't yet check it, but I hope that it will work fine. Have a nice day.

Comment: I would advise using a bit more descriptive name for annotate/alias. But that's nitpicking ;)

Comment: It's working. How can I get the comment count for each post in the template by using for loop?

for example 

{% for post in posts %}

{{ post.comment.count }}

{% endfor %}

Comment: @PraveenKumar: if you use the variant with `.annotate(...)` (not `.alias`), you can render this with `{{ post.ncomment }}`.

Comment: Okay k. I forgot it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django's built-in [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) to sort by count.

For eg:

```
from django.db.models import Count

mydata = Comment.objects.annotate(count=Count('comment')).order_by('-count')
#you can replace 'comment' with your respective fieldname.
```